# What's the difference between 降{ふ}る and 落{お}ちる?

Tags: words

Things I've seen go with 降{ふ}る are rain, snow and leaves, e.g. 雪が降る。

I'm thinking 降る is used for small and light things. So, perhaps 'feathers' could be used like so 羽が降る, but apples would be りんごが落{お}ちる。

Appreciate your responses. Thanks!

Comment: Quantities > Weight.  If apples ever 降る, it will make front-page news.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [降る](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%99%8D%E3%82%8B) for its meaning explanation. It basically says that something, such as rain or snow, comes falling down over a wide area. The substance falling must be small, but plentiful.
Please note that the explanation given on the website cited includes the word 落ちる. Hence, 降る is the more specific verb that must fulfill more conditions in order to be used correctly.

Comment: @user5387 If you like the answer, please select it.